# Any particular checkbox is checked in multiple checkbox then other validation textfield is require in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.5

Any particular checkbox is checked in multiple checkboxes then another validation text field is required in Laravel.

I have Multiple checkboxes

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="item_1">
<input name="control_4[]" id="item_1" value="1" type="checkbox"> A
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="item_2">
<input name="control_4[]" id="item_2" value="2" type="checkbox"> B
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="item_3">
<input name="control_4[]" id="item_3" value="3" type="checkbox"> C
</label> 

<input type="text" name="try">
```

If I select item_2 and 3 then if item 3 exist in control_4 array then input box require otherwise not validation in inputbox.

```
$this->validate($request, [
'control_4' => 'required',
'try' => 'required'
]);
```

How to make validation in Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define rule on try input like :

```
$this->validate($request, [
'control_4' => 'required',
'try' => 'partialRequired'
]);
```

Then you must define your partialRequired method's definition:

```
class customValidation extends Validator
{

    public function validatePartialRequired($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if(in_array('3',$this->data['control_4']) && empty($value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```